# get the Message count and last offset of each partition of topic in Java

Tags: apache-kafka

Using Admin Client to communicate with Kafka in Java code. we are able to do all the CRUD operations on particular topic. Our new requirement is to get the number of messages for topic, Size of all messages for Topic, Last Offset for each partition of Topic.

Input: Broker List and Topic
Expected Output like below for 5 partitions

```
{
  "total": 10,
  "partitions": [
    3,
    2,
    1,
    3,
    1
  ],
  "offsets": [
    10,
    9,
    9,
    11,
    12
  ]
}
```

Total is the size of message in bytes.

Tried using the Consumer group ID. Here we will be able to get the data only if the topic is consumed.We want to get the topic details regardless it is consumed or Not.

Please suggest possible apporaches

Comment: You won't be able to easily get number of total messages in a topic at any point in time since retention and log deletion is a moving window (plus that question has been asked before, if you search). The size of a topic can be found from JMX metrics.

Comment: I am getting the message count for topic by subtracting beginning offsets from end  offsets for each partition like below. I need current message count and it is OK if i dont get any message beyond retention hours. Is this right approach or  any other API's available to access through java?
consumer.endOffsets(partitions).get(topicPartition) -consumer.beginningOffsets(partitions).get(topicPartition)

Comment: That count will only work for non-compacted topics. That looks like the correct APIs to me.

Answer (score 4):

Using Commandline, you can collect the offsets for each partition of a topic in following way:

```
kafka%~ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic mytopic1
```

It will return the offsets per partition as below:

```
mytopic1:2:828012
mytopic1:1:827041
mytopic1:3:829577
mytopic1:0:829184
```

Here you can refer more detail : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools

Comment: This gets last offset, but not the other data asked for in the question....